# Clear duplicates not geting closed because of a low number of views

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Four days ago, I answered [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3607/how-to-get-a-top-view-using-open-cv) migrated from SO. Two days later, a [practically identical question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3628/virtually-rotating-the-view-with-intrinsic-and-extrinsic-parameter-known) was posted here, and as the tags were in my field, I saw it, provided a link to the duplicate question and voted to close.

But, as this site is still in beta, and most users have specific areas of expertise among all the areas covered with this site, the question did not attract many views. As it is really a duplicate, and not that well written, it did not (as expected) get any upvotes, and as such attracted even less views. Among that, some of the users that open decide it's not interesting to them, don't bother to check if it is a duplicate or do not have the power to vote to close.

As a result, a clear duplicate question is taking a long time to close. Is there any way to speed up this process on small beta sites such as this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the [review page](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/review), you'll find a list of tasks that need to be reviewed. One of them is posts with pending close votes. So far, Jonsca is the only person that has ever reviewed and voted to close and there are 13 posts currently in the queue (as I can see it... different people see different numbers). Another place to look for posts with recent close votes is in the [tools page](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last30days) (you need at least 2k rep).

Now, I do monitor these queues, but I generally don't vote to close unless it has 3-4 close votes already (or if it is extremely terrible). This is because my vote, as a moderator, is binding and I'd like to see some community effort/agreement in closing. In the early days of this site, I was more active in closing duplicates and slamming shut the localized/off-topic and non-constructive questions to guide the site (and new users) when it's young. Back then, we only had two 2k+ users (myself and Jason), whereas now we are over a year old and have 11 users with 2k+ rep (and access to tools), and about 50 or so with the privilege to close, so there is no need for me or the other mods to be as proactive as before. If everyone pitched in a little (posts also need editing), then things will move a lot smoother and faster :)

So please, make use of the review queue. If you see something that needs fixing/editing, please do so. Something doesn't belong here? Vote to close. If you find something that is old and needs to be closed, but will not get much attention because of its age, then flag it.